# Without exposing his identity, did Roy help his parents with money so that they can afford to stay in their home?

Tags: plot-explanation, knight-and-day

In *Knight and Day* Roy's mother says that they won Publishers Clearing House and other lotteries. His father says "I didn't buy those lotteries".

Without exposing his identity, did Roy help his parents with money, by making fake lottery winning arrangements so that his parents can afford to stay in their home?

Answer (score 10):

## Yes

It's not *explicitly* stated that Roy has been faking their winnings.

However, it becomes a practical **certainty** when, in the closing scene, we hear that they have won tickets to **Cape Horn** where Roy and June are now supposed to be living.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_and_Day)

> Waking up in June’s rebuilt GTO, Roy and June drive toward Cape Horn, and Roy's parents unexpectedly receive their own tickets to Cape Horn.